# How to mock static methods in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jmockit

I'm trying to mock a static method with jMockit in Kotlin:

```
object: MockUp<System>() {
  @Mock
  fun getProperty(name: String) = "tagB"
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Could not load Logmanager "tagB"
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tagB
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:195)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:181)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager.(LogManager.java:181)
>       at java.util.logging.Logger.getPlatformLogger(Logger.java:572)
>       at java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl.getLogger(LoggingProxyImpl.java:41)
>       at sun.util.logging.LoggingSupport.getLogger(LoggingSupport.java:100)
>       at sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$JavaLoggerProxy.(PlatformLogger.java:602)
>       at sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$JavaLoggerProxy.(PlatformLogger.java:597)
>       at sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger.(PlatformLogger.java:239)
>       at sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger.getLogger(PlatformLogger.java:198)
>       at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.config(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:142)
>       at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:165)
>       at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:178)
>       at java.util.Formatter.getZero(Formatter.java:2283)
>       at java.util.Formatter.(Formatter.java:1892)
>       at java.util.Formatter.(Formatter.java:1914)
>       at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
>       at org.junit.runner.Description.formatDisplayName(Description.java:114)
>       at org.junit.runner.Description.createTestDescription(Description.java:73)
>       at io.kotlintest.TestCase.getDescription(testcase.kt:45)
>       at io.kotlintest.TestBase.descriptionForSuite$kotlintest_main(TestBase.kt:153)
>       at io.kotlintest.TestBase.getDescription$kotlintest_main(TestBase.kt:39)
>       at io.kotlintest.KTestJUnitRunner.getDescription(KTestJUnitRunner.kt:11)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.getDescription(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:123)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:99)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Logging configuration class "tagB" failed
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tagB
>   ...

Other approaches with expectations blocks weren't successful, too.

How can I mock a static method in Kotlin?

Comment: Why don't you refactor your code so that it allows to pass whatever value you're accessing through `System.getProperty` through an explicit API?

Comment: In this case, there is nothing to mock: just call `System.setProperty(...)`.

Comment: @Rogério `System.setProperty` is not an option (acutally it is the current "solution"), because it interferes with other tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should mock System like this:

```
class MockSystem : MockUp<System>() {
    @Mock
    fun getProperty(name: String) = "tagB"
}


class MockTest {

    val m = MockSystem();

    @Test fun test() {
        Assert.assertEquals(System.getProperty("hello"), "tagB")
    }
}
```